# How to set a variable value based on if-statement in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to assign a value to a variable based on an if-else statement in a batch file. I am searching a text file for a string and if the string is found I need to assign a certain value to the variable.

I have used the if-else statement to assign the value but after exiting the if-else statement when I try to echo the variable i get value as 0

```
@echo off

set "logfile=results.txt"
find /n /i "Orientation      : 0" "%logfile%" >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    set org = "landscape"

) else (
    set org = "portrait"

)

echo %org%
```

The output for this should be 'landscape', I have verified that the string does exist in the file. For some reason, I am getting 0 as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space around the equal sign:

```
set org="landscape"
set org="portrait"
```

Comment: Works! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the already provided answer, *where it has been highlighted that you have used spaces either side of your **`=`** character*. It means that you are setting, for example:
**<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>**.
Unless you remove those spaces, you'd need to **`Echo`:
<kbd>%</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd>**
to see the value you'd set, *(and that also includes the doublequotes)*.

I would additionally suggest that you use this syntax:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "logfile=results.txt"
Set "org="
Find /I "Orientation      : 0" <"%logfile%" >Nul && (
    Set "org=landscape"
) || (
    Set "org=portrait"
)
Echo %org%
```

Alternatively, using `FindStr` gives you a little manoeuvre with the existence or number of spaces, e.g. the following would still match:
**`Orientation:0`**
or
**`Orientation : 0`**

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "logfile=results.txt"
Set "org="
FindStr /IRC:"Orientation[\ :]*0" "%logfile%" >Nul && (
    Set "org=landscape"
) || (
    Set "org=portrait"
)
Echo %org%
```

*Put into simple terms, the conditional operators **`&&`** and **`||`** effectively mean, if the previous command was successful and if the previous command failed, respectively.*

Comment: thank you for going out f your way to give an optimal answer! I have a follow up if you don't mind : 
```
@echo off

SET VAR=portrait
IF "%VAR%" == "portrait" do (
 SET /a height=1920;
 set /a width=1080;
) else do(
 set /a height=1080;
 set /a width=1920;
)

echo %height%

```
this gives me value of height as 1080 rather than the expected value of 1920. Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: @SourabhSriom, I have provided a solution to your comment as an answer to your other question.